# I have changed package name of the project but when i am creating apk it shows the package name different in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, adb

I have changed package name from `com.example` to `com.test` of the project, but when I ran the project again, on the **run** console it shows `adb shell am start -n "com.example"` instead of `adb shell am start -n"com.test"`.

Comment: Rename also package name in `AndroidManifest.xml` and rename folders manully too. Also I suggest you to not play too much with package renaming bcs you can get confused

Comment: I did that but didn't help thank you for reply. Samvid answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check manifest file and also the project gradle file. In my case gradle file was not updated (dont know why).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to rename package name in `AndroidManifest` file, Android system takes package name from there.

it should lokk like below.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="**com.test**" // change this
```

Comment: I did that but didn't help thank you for reply. Samvid answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

go to android manifest and change name of your package

Comment: I did that but didn't help thank you for reply. Samvid answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

go to the project structure then click on your app folder then go on flavors and change your app id to correct